# sharing session between php and jsp

Tags: php, jsp, session

We have some web pages written in JSP and a few others written in PHP.

What we're trying to accomplish is that, whenever a user login (through a PHP page), we want to save the session information (userid, login time, etc) and use the same information when accessing JSP pages as well.

How can we share JSP and PHP session information with each other using same session id?

Is there a way to do that, or are they automatically compatible with each other?

Comment: I would suggest using a common database table to store session information, and just write your own session handling routines for each language.

Comment: Thanx Scuzzy.Is there any better way to do that? In this case we have to delete session information from database on logout. But what happen in case user close browser or turn off his system widout logout? We left with multiple useless entries in db.

Comment: Ok, the user closing browser problem can be addressed with the cookie itself, an empty or 0 expiration will expire the cookie (and thus the session id) on browser close. From there you can build your own garbage collection function to clean up the session table that have been inactive for a certain period. The simplest way to handle this is right before validating the login details, clean up old rows based on a last used timestamp, Idealy you might want to just do this before every session update, to ensure users who have left their conneciton idle for too long are automaticaly logged out.

Answer (score 3):

You should have a common distributed  session management, which the PHP and JSP pages will use to retrieve sesssions. You also need to have request wrappers for JSP and PHP which overrides getSession() and delegates the session management to your custom distributed session management.

I do not know how to wrap requests in PHP, but for JSP's, you can have a filter which will create a request wrapper.

The common distributed session management should take care of session management lifecycle such as:

1. Creating Sessions if no session exists with the given id.
2. Lookup session if session exists with the given id.
3. Invalidate session when user does logout, i.e, when the page does session invalidation.
4. Invalidate session if the session is idle for given timeout. A session management thread should validate the sessions at given interval and invalidate the session which have exceeded the timeout value.